# How to speed up Timing[4^(10^10)]

Tags: performance-tuning, timing, system-performance

I have an old computer with a quad-core AMD Phenom II processor (3Ghz). When I run `Timing[4^(10^10)]`the computer takes hours to evaluate the expression. I'm not sure how long, because Windows decided my computer was idle, installed updates, and rebooted, losing my work :(. I'm currently re-running the process in Linux. However, I notice in Linux that *Mathematica* is only using one core. What can I do to speed up the process? I have seen that using floating point i.e. `Timing[4.^(10^10)]`might work, but this is for school so I have to use the code as written.

Comment: I really wonder what you would do with it when the computation will have finished...

Comment: I think, whatever question you're trying to answer for school, they don't _actually_ want you to compute the value in full. There's probably a trick to accomplish to compute what you need without actually getting the large value.

Comment: You might need modular exponentiation (`PowerMod`). E.g. `PowerMod[4, 10^10, 97]`

Comment: I think the professor wanted us to understand the importance of careful choices of code. Obviously if you include code that takes hours to run, you may defeat the purpose of using a computer to do the work. We were also asked to speculate on why 2^(10^10) took several seconds to evaluate, whereas 3^(10^7) took only a fraction of a second. I said I thought it was because 10^7 is three orders of magnitude smaller than 10^10.

Comment: `{ t, num } = Timing[ 4^(10^10) ] ;` may not take too long. (The semicolon is important.)  But don't try to display `num` as an integer. Try `N[ num ]` instead. Maybe check `MemoryInUse[ ]` before and after. Does the memory usage make sense for num ?

Comment: *Mathematica* computes in binary. It takes about one second to compute your number on my machine. But the decimal representation of `4^(10^10)` has about six billion digits. Converting the binary number to decimal and displaying it would require considerable resources. Rather impractical.